# How do I find the minimum number of nodes in a directed graph from the number of edges?

Tags: math, graph, directed-graph

When reading from a file I get the number of edges In a directed graph. I then need to create a graph and specify the number of nodes it minimum can have.

I can't figure out how many nodes the graph min can have based on the number of edges.

More of a math problem, dunno if im stupid or something.

Need an integer to represent it. So I can't just solve Y=X*(x-1) for x since edges = nodes(nodes - 1). so what's the closest integer I can be pick to be sure that I have enough nodes.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954096/whats-the-minimum-number-of-vertices-in-a-simple-graph-with-e-edges but that's on another site.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum number of nodes would be 2.  The two nodes have all the edges between them.

[image]

To get a more sensible answer, you need to specify more constraints ( e.g. maximum out degree )  For that, you will need to describe the reason you want to do this.